# Return single list of map value

Tags: terraform

I need to dynamically configure parameters values in `instances` so that the value can *overwrite* `default_parameters` value. Below the sample code.

vars.tf

```
variable "instances" {
  type = map(object({
    suffix              = string
    modify_type         = string
    parameters          = list(map(string))
  }))
 }

variable "default_parameters" {
  type = list(map(string))
}
```

And the problem is, I need to use terraform `merge` function but it just accept map or object, how to convert the parameters to map?

```
  dynamic "parameters" {
    for_each = merge(var.default_parameters, var.instances[each.key].parameters)
    content {
      name  = parameters.value.name
      value = parameters.value.value
    }
  }
```

Comment: I guess your "marge" should be order aware of your items in the `default_parameters` list?

Comment: @Marcin, sorry I am not quite understand. But I got this error: `Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "list
of map of string".`

Comment: What if you have two items in `default_parameters` and the same items are in `parameters`, but in different order. They are lists after all. What happens then? Do default all values are used, or all values from  `parameters`?

Comment: Also, can you change the format of these variables, or they can't be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest different format. Instead of list of maps, just use map:

```
variable "instances" {
  type = map(object({
    suffix              = string
    modify_type         = string
    parameters          = map(string)
  }))
  
  default = {
      "00" = {
        suffix              = "00-live"
        modify_type         = "Upgrade"
        parameters = {
            connect_timeout = 80
            name = "my_instance"
          }
      }
    }  
 }

variable "default_parameters" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
            connect_timeout = 100
            name = "default_name"
      }
}
```

then:

```
  dynamic "parameters" {
    for_each = merge(var.default_parameters, var.instances[each.key].parameters)
    content {
      name  = parameters.key
      value = parameters.value
    }
  }
```